# UE4 19.2, Packaging Unknown Error for Windows

Tags: fatal-error, packaging, unreal-engine4, blueprint

sorry for taking your time, I'm having trouble packaging my game for Windows with.
It didn't work with Visual Studio 2017 and neither with 2015.
Problematic part of my Output Log: (The bold lines are Errors, and the others are Messages)

---

> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'X:\MyGame\Binaries\Win64\MyGame.exe'
>
> **UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   ERROR: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: X:\MyGame\Binaries\Win64\MyGame.pdb**
>
> **PackagingResults: Error: UBT ERROR: Failed to produce item: X:\MyGame\Binaries\Win64\MyGame.pdb**
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):   Total build time: 26.35 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): Took 26.7634315s to run UnrealBuildTool.exe, ExitCode=5
>
> **UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): ERROR: Command failed (Result:5): C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.19\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe MyGame Win64 Development -Project=X:\MyGame\MyGame.uproject  X:\MyGame\MyGame.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="X:\MyGame" -skipdeploy -noxge -NoHotReload -ignorejunk. See 
>   logfile for details: 'UnrealBuildTool-2018.11.28-15.33.44.txt'**
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)):        (see C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Roaming\Unreal Engine\AutomationTool\Logs\C+Program+Files+Epic+Games+UE_4.19\UAT_Log.txt for full exception trace)
>
> **PackagingResults: Error: Command failed (Result:5): C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.19\Engine\Binaries\DotNET\UnrealBuildTool.exe MyGame Win64 Development -Project=X:\MyGame\MyGame.uproject  X:\MyGame\MyGame.uproject -NoUBTMakefiles  -remoteini="X:\MyGame" -skipdeploy -noxge -NoHotReload -ignorejunk. See logfile for details: 'U
>   nrealBuildTool-2018.11.28-15.33.44.txt'**
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=5 (5)
>
> UATHelper: Packaging (Windows (64-bit)): BUILD FAILED
>
> **PackagingResults: Error: Unknown Error**
>
> LogSlate: Window 'Output Log' being destroyed

---

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't actually know anything about Unreal yet, but it looks like you have your Project Path defined twice behind the `-project=<Project Path>.uproject` option.